# A question about NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, xcode, interface-builder

There is a check box titled "Continuous" under the "Control State" section in the TableView attributes dialogue box.  I don't seem to be able to find any description about it.  The only thing I know about it, is it is unchecked  by default and my sample tableView object doesn't display anything unless it is checked.  Can anybody more knowledgable tell me what does "Continuous" state mean here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isContinuous` and `setContinuous:` are methods of `NSControl`, which is a superclass of `NSTableView`. In the context of `NSTableView`, this property has no effect, it is just an unused aspect of the superclass. Other `NSControl` subclasses, such as `NSSlider` use it to signify that their value should be updated continuously during mouse tracking.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed explanation.  Have just checked again, the sample tableView does work even the "Continuous" check box is unchecked now.  But previously I only got it to work after it is checked.  May be it was just a coincidence or I just got the IB file saved as a side effect of the check/uncheck process ...